# How To Access Class A Folder To Be Used In Another Class

Tags: c#

I am using C#
Scenario: Same project

```
FolderA - ClassA
FolderB - ClassB
```

I have a method in ClassB that needs the  methods from ClassA.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder part does not matter, but one common way to expose methods to other classes is to make them public. You can either use static or instance methods.

Ex

```
public class A
{
   public void SomeMethod(){}
   public static void SomeStaticMethod(){}
}

public class B
{
  public B()
  {
     A a = new A();
     a.SomeMethod();

     A.SomeStaticMethod();
  }
}
```

Another alternative is to use inheritance and let class A  inherit from class B

```
public class A : B
{
   public A()
   {
      //you can now call the methods defined in B
      base.SomeMethod();
   }
}
```

Above is an example of how to do it.