# How To Call A Class To Be Used In A Method Of Another Class

Tags: c#

Scenario:

FOLDER: Connection

```
public class Connection 
{
    public void ServerConnect ()
    {
    . . . .
    }
}
```

FOLDER: Client

```
public void Connect 
{
     //In here, I want to implement the method from ServerConnect
}
```

How can I call ServerConnect?

Comment: You already ask the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803234/how-to-access-class-a-folder-to-be-used-in-another-class

Comment: What are the namespaces? Are they in the same project?

Comment: @BSoD_ZA, they have different namespaces
But same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object of `Connection` and then call `ServerConnect()` on it:

```
public void Connect{
   public void Foo(){
     Connection con = new Connection();
     con.ServerConnect();
   }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the they are in the same project or the DLL has been added as a reference.

Comment: @BSoD_ZA that's assumed :-P

Comment: they are in the same project. i will try this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call classes.

```
public void Connect 
{
     //In here, I want to implement the method from ServerConnect
     Connection c = new Connection();
     c.ServerConnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create object for Connection class and call the method like

```
Connection obj=new Connection();
 obj.ServerConnect();
```